# Spring integration: multiple transformers per message

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have quite a complex translation layer to write where each message requires many rules applied. I was hoping to keep this in XML if possible, since each rule is fairly simple.

So is it possible to have mulitple transformers applied to each message? I could join them together on different channels but this seems a bit unweildly. Is there an alternative pattern I could use to apply many rules to each message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<chain...>
    <transformer ... />
    <transformer ... />
</chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question ins't clear.

Be more specific and share, please, existing PoC.

Consider to use `<router>` and `<enricher>`.

From other side, if your logic is so complex, you can always wrap it to some POJO and invoke its method from `<transformer>`.

Comment: So I specificially want to avoid writing POJO based transformers. Basically I wanted to write a series of transforer SpEL statements to convert between different but similar types. No POC as of yet.

Comment: `<router>` and `<filter>` should help you. From other side I sometimes use `<gateway>` within `<chain>` to reuse `request-channel` sub-flow from different flows.